# Binder invocation to an incorrect interface

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I tried to build android app for android box. In my scenario my app need to stream live TV channels by using HDMI input.Why am I getting this kind of exception? 
Any help to slow this error would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.danman.zidostreamer.zidostreamer/eu.danman.zidostreamer.zidostreamer.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
   at com.mstar.android.tv.ITvService$Stub$Proxy.getTvCommon(ITvService.java:365)
   at com.mstar.android.tv.TvManager.getTvCommon(TvManager.java:205)
   at com.mstar.android.tv.TvCommonManager.getService(TvCommonManager.java:136)
   at com.mstar.android.tv.TvCommonManager.getCurrentInputSource(TvCommonManager.java:166)
   at eu.danman.zidostreamer.zidostreamer.MainActivity.changeInputSource(MainActivity.java:49)
   at eu.danman.zidostreamer.zidostreamer.MainActivity.enableHDMI(MainActivity.java:69)
   at eu.danman.zidostreamer.zidostreamer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.